# Relative path to a web application project in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, relative-path

Hi all I have a project that i reference the services for my graphs...and i have hardcoded urls something like -

```
ViewData["weeklyGraphURL"] = "\"http://localhost:9713/MyProject/MyAction"+Id + "\"";
```

So this url is basically another projects controller action...and i have both these projects in one solution...is there a way i could set a relative path to this  project when I deploy it on the web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are always going to live on the same machine you could look at reading the server name out of Request.ServerVariables.Get("SERVER_NAME") and replacing localhost with that.

Comment: ya but what about the port number...is there any way i could get it?

Comment: That's available via the SERVER_PORT server variable.  

Here's a list of all of the IIS server variables that are available:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=VS.90%29.aspx